# Failed pipline on slave

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want implement next:
[image]
Here is my pipline script:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
}
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'node --version'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If I run my pipline only on master it is work. But if I run this pipline on slaves I will get next error:

```
    Started by user Daniil
    [Pipeline] node
    Running on agent-1 in /var/jenkins/workspace/just another check
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup)
    [Pipeline] sh
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: /var/jenkins/workspace/just another check
        at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1171)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask$FileMonitoringController.(FileMonitoringTask.java:154)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript$ShellController.(BourneShellScript.java:198)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript$ShellController.(BourneShellScript.java:190)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:111)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:86)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:176)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:19)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.pull(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:143)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:66)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.pull(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:142)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.DockerPipelineScript.runImage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/DockerPipelineScript.groovy:45)
        at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:103)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:60)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:243)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:231)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Finished: FAILURE
```

I think that my slave doesn't have docker. But I am not sure. I installed docker on master by bash after docker launched master.

Comment: seems the user of slave used to connect to master has no permission to create directory ` /var/jenkins/workspace/just another check` for job's workspace.  Find out that user and check its permission.

Comment: How I can check premission on slave? I am new in Jenkins. I created node in web application.